# On release mode cout does not print anything

Tags: c++, release, cout

I have a very weird problem. I am working with visual studio in C++ and suddenly cout does not work on release mode (It worked until now) and on debug mode it works fine. I have no idea why thats happans. I have tried to delete some code And I deleted almost all my program (I have backup). Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow )
{
    AllocConsole();
    cout<<"asdasd"<<endl;

    cin.get();
    return 1;
}
```

In debug mode the program wait for the user for pressing Enter. In release mode it doesn't. The window just close.

I think that it might be a problem in the setting of visual. Can it be?

Comment: Replace `while(true);` by `cin.get();`.

Comment: I replaced in and the program "blinked" in release mode. The window just appeared and closed

Comment: Did you hold any keys while doing that? Release mode configuration usually means that the console closes as soon as the program finishes, but it should wait for a key press because of `cin.get()`. You did put the `cin.get()` **before** `return 1;`, right?

Comment: Yes do not worry I did. It just jumped over that function.. weird :/
I edited the  post.

Answer (score 1):

iostreams require initialization that's normally carried out by the startup code for a console application -- but since you're using `WinMain` instead of `main` as your entry point, it's being linked as a Windows-mode application instead of a console-mode application, so that initialization isn't happening (dependably, anyway). Under some (poorly defined) circumstances, things work anyway, but it's undependable at best.

Unless you're feeling so masochistic that you're willing to do a lot of extra work just to make your code non-portable, write your code the standard way:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout<<"asdasd\n";

    std::cin.get();
    return 1;
}
```

Short, simple, and dependable are all good things. Portable is kind of nice too.

Comment: I deleted alot of code to reduce the code to see the problem. I have a win32 window in the program (It is OpenGL). I have to use WinMain, And until now It worked with it.

Comment: @user2320928: You can use `main` as the entry point, and still create windows, use OpenGL, etc., just fine.